# Hibernate HQL join fetch with constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to execute the following HQL statement:

```
       queryString = "select new DossierAccount(dossier,dossierAccount.accountNumber) from DossierAccount as dossierAccount join fetch dossierAccount.dossier as dossier" +
                  " where dossier.kycId.id != :kycId and dossierAccount.accountNumber in :accountNumbers";
```

This leads to a `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list` exception. When I remove the "fetch" it works. However the association between DossierAccount and Dossier is specified as "lazy" and I don't want to change it. But in this special case I need that the dossier is loaded eagerly.

It also works, when I replace the constructor call with the variable "accountNumber". But I need to reduce the number of selected properties here.

Is there a way to do this with an embedded constructor call in the select statement?

One further question: I also need to restrict the number of selected properties of the joined Dossier. Is there also a way to achieve this?

Comment: What happens when you remove `fetch` and keep the association `LAZY`?

Comment: The associated dossier is not loaded, but I need it in this case

Comment: What do you mean by not loaded, are there no values supplied to DossierAccount?

Comment: The DossierAccount is loaded, but the associated Dossier not. There is a many-to-one association defined to Dossier in the hibernate mapping of DossierAccount, which is not lazy.

Comment: But you are not using the entites directly, you are using a new-query. I doubt that would "load" any of the entities (depending on how you define "load", which was my question.)

Comment: I'm using only this one query. Rename "load" by "select". The Dossier referenced by the DosserAccount is not selected, because the association is defined lazy. Therefore I added the "fetch" in the query, to force the selection of the associated Dossier; and this doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "not selected"? Have you actually tried it in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm one step further. The following query selects at least the Dossier, without declaring the association between the DossierAccount and the Dossier eager:

```
        queryString = "select new DossierAccount((select dossier from Dossier as dossier where dossier.dossierId=dossierAccount.dossier.dossierId),dossierAccount.accountNumber) from DossierAccount as dossierAccount" +
                  " where dossierAccount.dossier.kycId.id != :kycId and dossierAccount.accountNumber in :accountNumbers";
```

For this purpose the following constructor is required:

```
public DossierAccount(Dossier dossier, AccountNumber accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.dossier       = dossier;
}
```

However this loads the whole Dossier data in memory, which I don't need. So I tried to select a restricted set of Dossier properties with the following statement:

```
        queryString = "select new DossierAccount((select new Dossier(dossier.kycId,dossier.relationshipName) from Dossier as dossier where dossier.dossierId=dossierAccount.dossier.dossierId),dossierAccount.accountNumber) from DossierAccount as dossierAccount" +
                  " where dossierAccount.dossier.kycId.id != :kycId and dossierAccount.accountNumber in :accountNumbers";
```

But this leads to a "ava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDataType() is not supported by ConstructorNode!" exception